# Choosing Payment Method disables Continue/Contribute buttons

Tags: joomla, payment-method

Running CiviCRM 5.12.4 and Joomla 3.9.5.
I am having a continuing problem with the Payment Method on paid events and registrations. We use Paypal and Pay Later on both profiles/events.

Paypal is the default. Leaving that without changing the payment option, the Continue/Contribute button works as expected. If you make any change to the payment options, the Continue/Contribute button gets disabled.

For online registration I created two profiles, one for Paypal and another for Pay Later. Ok workaround. For the event I cannot do that as we have a maximum number of attendant spaces.

I think this might be Joomla related as I found mention using Drupal, but the workaround doesn't fix the problem.

This is our first paid event and fixing this is critical for us. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Edit: The following error was noted when switching from Paypal to Pay Later.

> TypeError: CRM.loadPage is not a function[Learn More] index.php:835:7
>
> ```
> buildPaymentBlock https://www.rbsportsboosters.com/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/event/register&Itemid=1129&id=33&reset=1:835
>
> <anonymous> https://www.rbsportsboosters.com/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/event/register&Itemid=1129&id=33&reset=1:839
> ```

```
jQuery 2
```

Comment: Could you press "F12" on the page after making a change to a payment options and see if there are any errors in the "Console" tab?  If so, could you please edit your question to include them?  Thanks!

Comment: Updated original post. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

We are on Joomla 3.95 and CiviCRM 5.9.1. I do not understand why you would need two profiles for your event, as the 'Fee' tab allows both credit card processing and the pay later option. See:

https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/events/creating-an-event/

Comment: Two profiles are not needed, but the Payment Method function doesn't work correctly on our site and I needed a work around. It was the only solution that worked. Now that I see the event registration exhibits the same issue, I am looking for help.